# How to display all stores on the home page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, multistore, store-view, home-page

How in custom created module to make the logic of receiving and displaying all links to stores. The display should be on the homepage.

I tried the solution that suggested Google search, but I can’t finish the solution, because I don’t know how to put all the stores on the homepage.

```
public function __construct(
...,
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
...
     $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
....
private function getStoreData(){
    $storeManagerDataList = $this->_storeManager->getStores();
     $options = array();

     foreach ($storeManagerDataList as $key => $value) {
               $options[] = ['label' => $value['name'].' - '.$value['code'], 'value' => $key];
     }
     return $options;
}
```

Comment: How many website you have?

Comment: @Ranganathan 5, but in the future, I want to automatically add there as new stores arrive

Comment: 5 websites and each website having stores?

Comment: @Ranganathan no, no, I have a main site and it has Main Website Store -> Store View1, Store View2, Store View3 ...

Comment: got it will update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default block for this `Magento\Store\Block\Switcher`

Call phtml file with above block with below code

```
<?php foreach ($block->getStores() as $store): ?>
    <a href="#" data-post='<?= $block->getTargetStorePostData($store) ?>'>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($store->getName()) ?>
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Note:** Not only URL can switch the store, you need to set it in cookie using `data-post` attribute.

Call phtml file from xml like:

```
<block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="all_stores" template="Vendor_Module::stores.phtml"/>
```

Call phtml file from CMS page like:

```
{{block class="\Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="all_stores" template="Vendor_Module::stores.phtml"}}
```

Call you phtml from theme.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Module/Magento_Theme/templates/stores.phtml

anc call from cms block

```
{{block class="\Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="all_stores" template="Magento_Theme::stores.phtml"}}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn’t answer earlier. I understood correctly, if I insert your example in cms block, will I get all the links to my stores?

Comment: No  problem....Yes.....You can place your phtml in you theme and call it from cms block. I updated the answer.